# add_action for saving a custom menu

Tags: menus, actions

Say you have custom menus enabled with your WP theme. Is there any action associated with saving a menu once you've arranged it accordingly? To further clarify: say you've arranged a menu with some links and some posts, how might you get the titles of the posts in said menu upon saving (clicking the "Save Menu" button)?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you want to do with the results? Do you want to echo them in a theme file, store the configuration for later use, etc...

Comment: To get down to the brass tacks: How would you be able to prevent posts that are in a menu from being shown in the loop?

Answer (score 4):

At least in 3.4.1, there is an action for that: wp_update_nav_menu

See [here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.1/wp-admin/nav-menus.php#L379).

Then you can get the items in your menu with something like:

```
add_action('wp_update_nav_menu', 'my_get_menu_items');
function my_get_menu_items($nav_menu_selected_id) {
    $items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($nav_menu_selected_id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no dedicated action for your needs, but you can misuse the `'check_admin_referer'` hook. See the `switch ( $action )` block in `wp-admin/nav-menus.php` for details and other options.

Sample code for a start:

```
add_action( 'check_admin_referer', 'check_nav_menu_updates', 11, 1 );

function check_nav_menu_updates( $action )
{
    if ( ( 'update-nav_menu' != $action ) or ! isset( $_POST['menu-locations'] ) )
    {
        return;
    }

    $nav_locations = $_POST['menu-locations'];
    $nav_title     = $_POST['menu-name'];

    // do something awesome with it.
}
```

Comment: This seems like a pretty good answer. I'll give it a try, but before I do, could you explain how using 'check_admin_referer' would be a misuse?

Comment: @Comradefuzz This action happens in a context of _security_, it is made to implement your own reactions to attackers and similar issues. Plus, the function is pluggable: it could be replaced by another plugin. And then the hook may not work anymore. Another solution would be to hook into `'updated_option'` and search for `'theme_mods_' . get_option( 'stylesheet' )[get_theme_mods()]['nav_menu_locations']`. But this is a long way, WordPress may change one aspect of it later, and your script may break too.